# How to work on elements within certain elements using plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to find element within the element in javascript not jquery or any other?

My code is something like below-

```
<p class="error ">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Your company name *">                
</p>
<p>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Your company address *">             
</p>
```

I want to find the element with class- **error** and if there is a class, I want to find the inner element of parent element. If it is type **input or select** then need to add a class to it.

In my case in the first element **"P"** contains **"error"** class. So I want to find the internal element of this element **"P"** and if the element is type **input** then I need to add border color of that text box.
So the first textbox should applied new css property.

Thanks,
Keep coding ....

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all input fields or selectboxes to be treated you will need to use `.querySelectorAll()` and then `.forEach()`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.error input,.error select')
        .forEach(e=>e.classList.add('brdr'))
```

```css
.brdr {border: 1px solid red}
```

```html
<p class="error">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Your company name *"><br>
   <input type="number" placeholder="some number"><br>
   <select><option>a</option><option>b</option><option>c</option></select>                
</p>
<p>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Your company address *">             
</p>
<p class="error">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Your customer's name *"><br>
   <input type="number" placeholder="number two">
</p>
```